# If $M \otimes N=0$ then prove that either $M=0$ or $N=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

This question was asked in my  assignment on tensor products and I think I need help to prove it.I have been following Atiyah and Macdonald textbook.

> Question : (a) Let $A$ be a local ring, $M$ and $N$ are finitely generated $A$-modules. Prove that if $M \otimes_A N =0$ , then either $M=0$ or $N=0.$

Attempt: Let $\{ m_1,...,m_n\}$ and $\{ n_1,...,n_p\}$ be a generating set of M and N respectively.

So, I can write element of $M\otimes_A N$ as $(a_1m_1+ ...+a_n m_n)\otimes (a_1n_1+...+a_p n_p)$=$(a_1m_1 \otimes a_1 n_1) + ...+(a_1m_1 \otimes a_p n_p)+(a_n m_n\otimes a_1 n_1)+...+(a_n m_n \otimes a_p n_p)=0$. Now, I can write each of the single term as following for example: $(a_1m_1\otimes a_1n_1)=0$ implies that $a_1 a_1 (m_1\otimes n_1)$ but how can I proceed now to prove that either $M=0$ or $N=0$?

If I try by assuming that both $M$ and $N$ are nonzero  and try to find a contradiction still I will have to face the same problem. So, how do I proceed?

> (b) Prove that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \approx \mathbb{Z} / d{\mathbb{Z}}$.

I am unable to construct an isomorphism  from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} / d{\mathbb{Z}}$. Can you please suggest how should I construct the map? Rest I want to prove it by myself.

Kindly shed some light on this.

Thanks!

Comment: NB: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Comment: You can't use the the statement in $(b).$ This is because $\Bbb{Z}$ is not a local ring.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you cannot simply group terms across the tensor product symbol: $a\otimes b  +c\otimes d \ne (a+b)\otimes(c+d)$

Comment: $(b)$ is a duplicate. It has been shown here (if you can't find it I will post the links. But try to search yourself first).

Comment: (a)https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633040/let-a-be-a-local-ring-m-and-n-finitely-generated-a-modules-show-that-i

Comment: (a)https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321374/tensor-product-of-two-finitely-generated-modules-over-a-local-ring-is-zero

Comment: (b)https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269067/mathbbz-m-mathbbz-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-cong-mathbb?noredirect=1